# How to create column in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem in creating columns in bootstrap. Screenshot is attached, please tell me how to achieve this.

[image: Divide column and putting arrow in right]

I want to make it responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap provides a 12 col grid, so if you want a col with 100% width you can use .col-md-12 if you want to have 3 cols you can achieve it like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

4 because 12/4 = 3 for 3 columns :)

also take a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/